# radGrid control displays blank grid after date parameter is changed

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, telerik, radgrid

I searched SO, google & Telerik forums, but could not find a solution.

I have an existing app (written by a previous developer) that is  calling a stored procedure that populates a RadGrid control. It populates fine the first time around.

However, when I change the date parameter, click "search" button, I get a blank  RadGrid control. When I click search the second time, the grid is populated. When I walk through the code, I get an error message

> Column 'ID' does not belong to table Table.

How can I resolve the issue of having to click search twice to display data ?

My code behind is:

```
protected void btnSubmit_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        ViewState["newset"] = null;
        CreateDatasource();
        this.RadGrid1.DataBind();
        this.RadGrid1.CurrentPageIndex = 0;
        ViewState["newset"] = "new";    

        string idex = this.hdnindex.Value;
        if (idex != string.Empty)
            this.RadGrid1.MasterTableView.Items[int.Parse(idex)].Selected = true;

     }
     catch (Exception ex) {
        this.lblMessage.Text = ex.Message; 
     }         
}

protected void RadGrid1_ItemCreated(object sender, GridItemEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (e.Item is GridDataItem)
        {
            GridDataItem item = (GridDataItem)e.Item;
            HyperLink hLink = (HyperLink)item["ViewHyperLink"].Controls[0];
            if (hLink != null)
                hLink.Attributes.Add("onclick", "selectMe('" + item.ItemIndex + "');");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        this.lblMessage.Text = ex.Message;
    }
}
```

In the code behind above, when this.RadGrid1.DataBind() is called, the code steps into `RadGrid1_ItemCreated` loops through the if statement a few times, them goes into the if statement, comes out of the function, and then the catch statement of btnSubmit is called, which displays the error message "Column ID does not belong to table Table".

Any ideas on how to resolve this?

Comment: With an exception message like that, it sounds like there's a binding problem between the RadGrid and the data source.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Can you expand on that (or have any suggestions) ? I have tried pretty much every which way of binding I can think of.

Comment: Can you include your stored procedure and the logic that is populating the RadGrid?

Comment: One other thing: It looks like there were some issues with the GridHyperlinkColumn mysteriously throwing this error on rebinds with some specific versions of the RadControls.  Not sure if this applies to your scenario, but the thread is [here](http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-ajax/grid/column-does-not-belong-to-table-defaultview.aspx).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you should try [Grid - Simple Data Binding](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/programming/simplebinding/defaultcs.aspx). Also you this thread ([RadGrid NeedDataSource Page load](http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-ajax/grid/radgrid-needdatasource-page-load.aspx#929603)) on telerik forum talks in detail about Simple Data binding. I don't know if you are trying to use NeedDataSource, but I have had similar issues before and the Simple Data binding worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

That sure sounds like to me you need to call RadGrid1.Rebind() somewhere.  Try calling that for your last line in your try block inside btnSubmit_OnClick.

Also, what does this search button do? Does it filter the results based on a date?

Comment: No luck after trying your suggestion.